# In Linux,get content between two strings

Tags: linux, unix, sed, html-parsing

I want to use sed command for better performance :

```
sed -n '/<html>/,/<\/html>/p' filename > output
```

This command works well.
But I have multiple html tags in one file.
And I want to extract content between first occurence of HTML tags
  ,

Comment: No, you are **not** parsing HTML using regexes! I dare you!

Comment: This question belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: No I am not parsing html.I need to get only the content of the html file.

Comment: I need to do this because we have multiple html tags associated with the file

Comment: Using regex is OK for any text files. If your file is a text file it is OK. (html is a text file).

Comment: Didn't you forgot about backslash before '/html>' ?

Comment: insert four spaces at begin of line to mark text as code block

Comment: My command is sed -n '/<html>/,/<\/html>/p' filename > output

Comment: @loentar: C source code is also text. I dare you to write a C parser using REs.

Comment: I don't see any word 'parser' in question. Mann wan't to get some content from text file, not parse this file.

Comment: Can anyone please Help me ??? I am not parsing the html file.

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't see a HTML has multiple html tags. I guess it was just a text file filled with some html tags. may not be xml either...

Comment: "I am not parsing html.I need to get only the content of the html file."  Then you are parsing the HTML file.

Comment: @AndyLester if it was a html file `<html>foo</html>` I want to extract content of the file: `ml>foo</h`  is there a parser can do that? :D

Comment: @Kent: Yes, `sed -E 's,ml>([^<]+)</ht,\1,'`, or `tail -c+4 | head -c-5`. There seems to be the misconception here that if you are extracting some data from some larger set of data, that task can somehow be called something *other* than parsing. This is false; *all data extraction implies some level of parsing*. You don't have to extract all possible data from a file in order for it to be called parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should give you the first `<html>` block.

```
sed -n '/<html>/,/<\/html>/p;/<\/html>/q' file
```

example:

```
kent$  cat file
<html>
a
</html>
<html>
b
</html>
<html>
c
</html>

kent$  sed -n '/<html>/,/<\/html>/p;/<\/html>/q' file
<html>
a
</html>
```

btw, I don't think OP was parsing html/xml. html doesn't have multiple `<html>` tags. also his input file may not in xml at all.

Comment: this and also the string in question both are not working for me, can anyone suggest me what may be the problem

Answer (score 1):

So let's say you want to extract the content between <html> .. </html> delimiters, but you have multiple sets of delimiters in your text file. For example;

```
blah <html> this </html> blah <html> that </html> blah
blah
<html>
the_other </html>
```

should return

```
this that the_other
```

(Notes:

1. The sed script the original poster gave works fine if there's only one pair of <html> .. </html> delimiters. The problem is multiple copies in the same file.
2. This is not "parsing HTML", by the way. The problem with using regular expressions is that true regular expressions can't match nested tags, and you can't nest <html> tags.)

Here's my stab at it (using perl):

```
perl -e '$/=""; $_=<>; while (m#\G(.*?)<html>(.*?)</html>#gs) {print "<html>$2</html>\n";}' filename > output
```

I believe this does what you want.

(Explanation:

1. `perl -e 'command'` runs the perl script `command`.
2. `$/=""` clears the record separator, so Perl treats the entire file as one "line".
3. `$_=<>` reads the entire file into the variable `$_`.
4. `while ($condition) {print "$stuff";}` is self-explanatory.
5. `m#$pattern#gs` matches $pattern globally (the `g`); the `s` allows `.` to match any char including `\n`. If you prefix the match by `m`, you can use any delimiter instead of `/`; I used `#`.
6. In the pattern `\G(.*?)<html>(.*?)</html>`, the `\G` represents the position of the most recent global match, the two `.*?` match any string of characters (the `?` makes the match non-greedy so we take the shortest match instead of the longest), and...
7. ...the `( )` capture the strings we used in variables `$1` and `$2`, so we can copy the string between `<html>`...`</html>` as `$2` in our print statement.)

Comment: ...Your exaplanation is too good,Basically I want to split a file based on HTML tags . Are you familiar with csplit command ? Is is possible for me to split the files using csplit efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Consider your file as a text file. If you need to parse HTML, you must use some HTML parser.

Please note, this code will work only if your tag with content is a single line.

If you just need to get *value of first tag* this line can help.

```
sed -n "/<html>/,/<\\/html>/{/>.*<\//{s/^[^>]*>\\([^<]*\\)<\\/.*/\1/gp;q}}" file.html
```

test file `file.html`:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <ccc>test1</ccc><bbb>test2</bbb>
    <ccc1>test3</ccc1><bbb1>test4</bbb1>
  </body>
</html>
```

test:

```
$ sed -n "/<html>/,/<\\/html>/{/>.*<\//{s/^[^>]*>\\([^<]*\\)<\\/.*/\1/gp;q}}" file.html
test1
```

---

To get value by tag name:

```
sed -n "/<html>/,/<\/html>/{/<$tag>/,/<\\$tag>/{s/.*$tag>\\([^<]*\\)<\\/$tag.*/\1/gp;q}}" file.html
```

test:

```
$ tag=ccc
$ sed -n "/<html>/,/<\/html>/{/<$tag>/,/<\\$tag>/{s/.*$tag>\\([^<]*\\)<\\/$tag.*/\1/gp;q}}" 11
test1
$ tag=bbb
$ sed -n "/<html>/,/<\/html>/{/<$tag>/,/<\\$tag>/{s/.*$tag>\\([^<]*\\)<\\/$tag.*/\1/gp;q}}" 11
test2
$ tag=ccc1
$ sed -n "/<html>/,/<\/html>/{/<$tag>/,/<\\$tag>/{s/.*$tag>\\([^<]*\\)<\\/$tag.*/\1/gp;q}}" 11
test3
$ tag=bbb1
$ sed -n "/<html>/,/<\/html>/{/<$tag>/,/<\\$tag>/{s/.*$tag>\\([^<]*\\)<\\/$tag.*/\1/gp;q}}" 11
test4
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But seriously I am not parsing the file.It's just that our document contains multiple html tags,I need to split the html files .And I really don't know how should I achieve it.using C , file handling I could have done it,but I believe Linux is a better way to do it.

Comment: I thought sed command is a better way,but FIRST OCCURRENCE of HTML tags is the big problem for a newbie in Linux like me.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice you need only first tag value without knowing tag name.

Answer (score 0):

Use grep -o to extract only the first `<html>...</html>` pair

```
grep -oP "^.+?</html>" filename |head -1 | sed -n '/<html>/,/<\/html>/p' > output
```

However, just as with `sed` by itself, this will only work if the `<html></html>` tags are always on the same line as each other.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1,/<\/html>/' input_file
```

#### Note:

This one-liner would start from the beginning of file to first end html block. If there are lines before start of first html block they will get printed too.

Comment: I would comment that, this awk line doesn't extract the 1st `<html>` block, but extracting `from the 1st line till the first </html>`. that is, it could fail if the first line is not `<html>`

Comment: @Kent True ... added that in the answer.

Comment: @Jaypal , Can you explain what is NR==1? Does it represent first occurence of </html> ???

Comment: @Mann No, `NR==1` represents the first line in your file.